# What is the best way to concatenate 2 lists into a new list in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections

into a Java application I have the following situation:

I have these 2 lists:

```
List<Twp1007Progetto> progettiDaValidare = progettoService.getListaProgettiConsultazione(consultazioneFilter);

List<Twp1007Progetto> progettiInValidazione = progettoService.getListaProgettiConsultazione(consultazioneFilter);
```

and I have to concatenate these 2 lists (respetivelly named **progettiDaValidare** and **progettiInValidazione** and put the result into a new list named **listaProgetti**.

What is the best way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listaProgetti = new ArrayList(progettiDaValidare);
listaProgetti .addAll(progettiInValidazione)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Twp1007Progetto> listaProgetti = new ArrayList<Twp1007Progetto>(progettiDaValidare);
listaProgetti.addAll(progettiInValidazione);
```